# Missing DLLs from Visual Studio Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vs-extensibility, vsx

I am currently working on upgrading my Visual Studio Extension from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2017.

I have installed the the necessary workloads from the installer and upgraded the project to .Net 4.6

I am unable to find the following DLLs in the installation:

1. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.dll -

   Required for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame
2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll

   Required for Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.UIHierarchyItemMarshaler

These two DLLs are required for my code to build and were referring to 12.0.0.0 earlier.

Does some one have any solution to this or point me to the right direction?

Regards,

Kaveesh

Answer (score -1):

Your operation system may not be Windows10.I think you can check for your computer's drive and update them.Especially be attention to the .Net Framework.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 Update 1 (15.1). It has all necessary frameworks installed. Just the DLLs are missing. BTW, how would operating system impact Visual Studio?

Comment: Because 10 has installed most things you need.I installed vs2017 several days ago and didn''t meet DLL's missing.Maybe you can reinstall vs one more time.Missing dll usually is your drive's problem.

Comment: All Right... Let me try Repairing the installation. Lets hope it works.